# Matillion S3 load component Issue

Tags: etl, matillion

I am loading data from S3 bucket to Landing table via S3 Load Component using Matillion ETL tool.

I have one records like below
000D3A8B328E|"Rila Borovets" AD||83634A3C|DDFS

Filed separator is | and while loading this records I am getting following error "err code: 1214    Delimited value missing end quote"

I want to load values as it coming from source without removing double quotes.
I have million of records and few are with double quotes and few are not. I am having issue for only those records which are having double quotes.

How do i handle this scenario.?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which Matillion ETL product you're using there (could be Matillion ETL for Snowflake, for Redshift or for Delta Lake on Databricks).

If you're targeting Snowflake, choose File Type CSV then the only non-default parameter you would need to set in your S3 Load component is to change the Field Delimiter to |

If you're targeting Redshift, choose Data File Type Delimited, and again the only non default parameter is setting the Delimiter to |